# Ultrafilter problem

Tags: logic, model-theory

could you help me with this problem, please?

If $U$ is a principal ultrafilter on $I$ such that $\{a\}\in U$. Show that $Ult(\mathfrak{A}_x:x\in I)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{A}_a$ and $[f]=f(a)$ for each $f$ and $j$, the embedding is the identity.

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of the symbols?

Comment: @egreg: Those are perfectly standard in model theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not everybody is fluent in model theory notation; questions here are supposed to be interesting for a wide audience, not only for the questioner and the answerer.

Comment: @egreg: Oh, I agree, but only to some extent. In the end of the day I can't really talk about mathematics in details (including symbols and terminology) with someone from differential geometry. I don't expect everyone on MSE to be able to understand model theory questions, but I do expect those who try to try and familiarize themselves with the basics of model theory first.

Comment: The use of the somewhat nonstandard notation $Ult$ for the ultraproduct suggests homework from the same class.

Comment: @Alex: The questions are not quite duplicate, but I voted to close anyway because the answers are quite similar.  In the other question $Ult_U(\cal A)$ denotes the ultrapower of $\cal A$ (and that use is quite standard in set theory), here the product is of structures which are not necessarily identical.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Recall that $Ult\models\varphi([f_1],\ldots[f_n])$ if and only if $$\{i\in I\mid\mathcal A_i\models\varphi(f_1(i),\ldots,f_n(i))\}\in U.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Recall that given $f , g \in \prod_{i \in I} A_i$, by definition we have that $f \sim_U g$ (that is, $f$ and $g$ are representatives of the same element of $\mathrm{Ult}_U ( \mathfrak{A}_i : i \in I )$) iff $\{ i \in I : f(i) = g(i) \} \in U$.  In the case of a *principal* ultrafilter, you should be able to simplify this condition.